# Transform XML with nested attributes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file with layout like this:

```
<root>
    <node>
        <descriptors>
            <attribute attr="important"/>
        </descriptors>
        <value>
            Some
        </value>
        <value>
            text
        </value>
        <value>
            here.
        </value>
    <node>
</root>
```

There are many nodes and each one is differentiated by the elements in the `descriptors` element. I need to extract the text so that I'd have this:

```
<element>
    Sometexthere.
</element>
```

I have an xsl transformation:

```
<xsl:template match="//attribute[@attr='important']">
    <element>
        <xsl:for-each select="../../value">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </element>
</xsl:template>
```

This instead just writes all the `value` elements in every `node` element in the file.
I think I don't really understand the way scoping works (like when `.` points to the current element/node, but what is the current element/node in the loop).

How should I approach this?

**EDIT**

My actual xsl stylesheet (I'm transforming a docx file):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <order>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </order>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="/w:document/w:body/w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val='Pealkiri1']">
        <name>
            <xsl:for-each select="w:t">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </name>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try matching the `node` element that contains `descriptors/attribute/@attr=...` instead of the `attribute` element itself.

The `for-each` context would then be relative to that `node`.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <order>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//node[descriptors/attribute/@attr='important']" />
    </order>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="node">
    <element>
        <xsl:for-each select="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This produces the same result, but it omits the `<element>` tag. So now it's only text. Pretty weird.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your stylesheet? I guess you're missing `<xsl:template match="/">` or are messing up an `<xsl:apply-templates ...>`.

Comment: I have the template matching `/`, but that just surrounds the text with my own root element (`order`).

Comment: The problem lies in your `apply-templates`: Without the `select` attribute, you will implicitely select all children. Since there were not templates defined, XSLT was using the default ones. The default templates always spew out the text but leave out the elements.

Comment: Okay, now I understand. This helped a lot!